# Український аналог англійського "kinda" і "kind of"?

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова

Наскільки небажаним являється використання слова "типу" в українській мові?

В цьому словнику "kind of" представлений з міткою "informal":
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/kind-of

Але мені здається, що слово "типу" не відповідає навіть informal нормам української мови. Я знаю, що можна використовувати такі вирази, як "щось на зразок", "щось на кшталт". Але що ви скажете про використання саме "типу"? І, можливо, існують більш кращі відповідники? (Як на мене, перевага "kinda" та "типу" ще в їх лаконічності, на противагу українським "щось на зразок", "щось на кшталт").

Та як би ви переклали це речення, щоб зберегти цю певну невизначеність в почутті "kind of strange" і водночас залишитись лаконічним:

> It was kind of strange to see him again

?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Саме слово *[тип](http://sum.in.ua/s/typ)* цілком літературне і перші його вживання цілком відповідали його літературному значенню:

> Ми поселилися в готелі типу all-inclusive.
>   Він установив бомбу годиннкового типу.
>   Я відвідав ресторан такого самого типу, як і вчора, тільки в іншій частині міста.

Уже від цього літературного значення слова *тип*, мені здається, пішло його вживання не лише, власне, для зазначення типу, а в значенні «на зразок», «на кшталт», «схожий на», «аналогічний/подібний до» тощо, а потім як вставного слова чи навіть слова-паразита:

> На сніданок я замовив щось типу лосося.
>
> Він, типу, підійшов до мене й каже…

Що в літературній мові має стояти замість «типу», залежить від контексту:

- У Вашому прикладі я б сказав:

  > Було **якось** дивно бачити його знову.
- Загалом для вираження непевності (і також приєднання фраз, що образно описують щось) використовують слова *буцім* (розм.), *буцімто* (розм.), *гейби* (розм.), *либонь* (розм.), *мов*, *мовби*, *мовбито*, *наче*, *начеб*, *начебто*, *немов*, *немовби*, *немовбито*, *неначе*, *неначебто*, *ніби*, *нібито*:

  > Він, типу, занімів.
  >   Він **наче** занімів.
- У багатьох випадках «на зразок», «на кшталт», «схожий на», «аналогічний/подібний до»:

  > Я замовив щось типу салату.
  >   Я замовив щось схоже на салат.
  >
  > Я був у будинку типу вчорашнього.
  >   Я був у будинку, подібному до вчорашнього.