# Чи граматично правильно вживати слово "типу" у якості слові "ніби"?

Tags: граматика

Чи граматично правильно вживати слово "типу" у якості слові "ніби"? Чи існує окремий паронім-прислівник "типу" як от слово "замок"?

Comment: Будь ласка, не публікуйте повторно [закриті і видалені запитання](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/7435/). Це запитання, так само, як і попереднє, не містить достатньої кількості подробиць, щоб відповісти на нього однозначно. Якби ви зробили спробу самостійно знайти відповідь, такі подробиці з'явилися б.

Comment: Ось [приклад](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5878/8) гарного оформлення майже такого само запитання.

Comment: Привіт! А мені шкода, що Ваше попереднє запитання закрили. Мені особисто здається, що воно принаймні частково актуальне — адже _[вже наявне на сайті обговорення](/q/5878) хоч і наводить альтернативи, але не розкриває питання, **у якій мірі конкретно це слово відповідає нормам**_. Єдине що: у нас на сайті зазвичай прийнято не просто поставити запитання, а й навести свої власні спроби пошуку відповіді. Чи могли б Ви додати до запитання щось таке?

Comment: …Маю на увазі: пошуку необов'язково саме на цьому сайті, але бодай якісь спроби розв'язання (наприклад: «[оцей словник](https://sum.in.ua/) не містить _типу_ окремим словом і серед значень слова _тип_ теж потрібного не наводить; але в дійсності слово очевидно вживають, наприклад, [у цьому інтерв'ю](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9mCmZii2F9A)»). Або якби Ви зробили пошук на цьому сайті й точно описали, чого саме бракує в попередніх обговореннях — було б, думаю, взагалі ідеально.

Comment: Але вважаю, що в будь-якому разі було неправильно кепкувати з Вас через описку (тим паче, що Ви її потім [виправили самостійно](/revisions/7435/2)).